# How should I delete objects in a vector

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector

I am making a program that uses an std::vector to hold a bunch of objects.

```
std::vector<Ball> balls;
for (int i = 0; i < ball.size(); ++i){
  if (...some condition...){
    //How should I delete balls[i]
  }
```

If I did this

```
std::vector<Ball> balls;
//put a bunch of balls in balls
for (int i = 0; i < ball.size(); ++i){
  if (...some condition...){
    balls.erase(balls.begin() + i);
  }
```

There is no dynamically allocated memory in each ball, so does this completely clean up balls[i]? Do I never have to worry about that ball existing on the ram?

Thanks for all the help guys!

Comment: Yes, the balls will be destroyed automatically.

Comment: This loop has a problem, though. When you erase element `i`, all the elements after it will be shifted down. Then when you increment `i`, you'll skip over the ball that just moved into its place.

Comment: Make sure to skip `++i` when you erase an item. Otherwise, you'll skip processing some items of the vector.

Comment: @RSahu Honestly, OP should either use the iterator returned by `erase`, or use the remove_if-erase idiom. Messing with indices manually just calls for unwanted off-by-one errors

Comment: @KABoissonneault, the answer by VladFromMoscow presents the right way to remove items from a vector. If the OP sticks with his strategy, it's important for them to know that pitfall.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious - Consider `typedef int * Ball` and the code to add `balls.push_back(new int(5));`. Are they getting deleted

Answer (score 0):

> *"There is no dynamically allocated memory in each ball, so does this completely clean up `balls[i]`? Do I never have to worry about that ball existing on the ram?"*

Yes you don't have to worry about the `Ball` class instance, but memory management is done by the `std::vector<>` class internally. So this doesn't mean that `std::vector<>` will shrink it's dynamically allocated memory for the removed items automatically.

With the current standard you can use [`std::vector<>::shrink_to_fit()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) to suggest the implementation to do so, after you have erased several items.

Comment: Shrink to fit doesn't "force" or guarantee anything. It is a non-binding request, as the page you linked to says.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the following

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

//...

std::vector<Ball> balls;
//...

balls.erase( std::remove_if( balls.begin(), balls.end(), 
                             [] ( const Ball &b ) { return somecondition( b ); } ),
             balls.end() );
```

Method erase will call destructors for all erased elements of the vector. In fact the class calls a placement deallocation function.

Comment: I think you meant to answer the question. This may be a more idiomatic piece of code, but it is not an answer to the stated question.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to apply erase_remove idiom for conditional clean up:

```
balls.erase(std::remove_if(balls.begin(), balls.end(),
               [] (const Ball& el) { //write your condition here;})balls.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

First when you call `erase()` on a vector the destructor of the type is called a number of times equal to the number of elements erased (C++11 23.3.7.5.5).  All of the elements that are after the erased elements are moved forward to take up the empty space.  We do not recover an memory with this operation as we are not changing the capacity of the container.

Secondly you can use the standard algorithm [std::remove_if()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) and a [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) to get rid of the elements that satisfy a certain condition.  Here is a little example of how that would work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> foo = {1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,6,7,8,9};
    std::remove_if(foo.begin(), foo.end(), [](int i){ if(i == 5) return true; else return false; });
    for (const auto & e : foo)
        std::cout << e << " ";
}
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9a75d01f850af24)